# Python - streaming Youtube videos using GET

Tags: python, youtube

Is it possible to use a HTTP GET request to stream YouTube videos?

I've looked at the Google YouTube API docs, it's not clear that this can be done.  There are packages like `pytube`, but they are meant to be used directly, not by using HTTP requests.

Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to reverse-engineer youtube's code in order to stream it by yourself, and it would not be necessarily possible to do with http only.